# Are all non-lazy beans guaranteed to finish loading when the http server starts in spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm using spring-boot to start an HTTP server. It contains the following two files:

*BeanUtils*

```java
@Service
public class BeanUtils implements ApplicationContextAware {

    public static ApplicationContext cxt;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        cxt = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

*MainController*

```java
@RestController
public class MainController {

    @GetMapping("/getData")
    public Object getData() {
        return BeanUtils.cxt.getBean("someBean").getData();
    }
}
```

Does spring guarantee to finish *all* the beans, including both `BeanUtils` and `MainController` when the server starts? If not, the user might get a `NullPointerException` when he/she tried to access `/getData` because the `BeanUtils` bean hasn't been loaded. I want to know if it's safe to write like this.

Answer (score 0):

you can try it.  before send /getData request, BeanUtils has been loaded when server starts.

Answer (score 0):

all the beans are instantiated on starting up in Spring IOC container, if it is a singleton bean(as are by default) an instance of bean is created at startup and passed wherever required and if not(prototype), an instance is created at the time required and passed. so in this case you won't get NullPointerException.